# How do you create flash images on the fly at the server side?

Tags: java, python, flash

The question just came up!

I have seen in web apps we get flash images generated on the fly how is it achieved?  Any api for programming languages (Java Python)?

PS: It's adobe flash movie / image or swf

Answer (score 1):

If by Flash images you mean JPG, PNG and GIF files then you use any of the standard server side software packages or language specific libraries that utilize these packages.

Here are the two most popular:

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

[GD](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page)

Python has [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (Python Imaging Library)

If you are referring to generating swfs then update the question and perhaps you can get some help on that too.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)

[Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/)